# rails - .find returns data from database but missing column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, object, find

Ok, i hope the title is descriptive enough but here's my problem. (i'm new to rails so let me know if i need more info as well)

I have a form to edit a user on `edit.html.erb`  This gets a `@user` object passed to it.  The code on my controller that gets this is:

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

I am using that object to pre-populate the fields on the `edit.html.erb` page.  Here are the columns in my database for users:

```
id
username
name
email
admin
active
created_at
updated_at
```

My problem is that for some reason the value of `email` is being left off of the object, thus the values all get shifted left.  For example, by using `<%= @user.inspect %>` on the `edit.html.erb` page this is what i get:

```
<User id: 2, username: "exampleuser1", name: "Kaylee Kuhic", nickname: "exampleuser1", email: "Default", selected_color_scheme: "0", is_admin: true, active: nil, date_last_logged_in: "2012-08-30 19:28:31", created_at: "2012-08-30 19:28:31", updated_at: nil>
```

This is just a test application i'm tinkering with so i may have moved a column around.  Would that affect it?  **What is happening between the controller and the view that could be affecting the object?**

Also, when i run `User.find(params[:id])` in the rails console i get all the data returned back correctly:

```
<User id: 2, username: "exampleuser1", name: "Kaylee Kuhic", nickname: "exampleuser1", email: "exampleuser1@example.com", selected_color_scheme: "Default", is_admin: true, active: true, date_last_logged_in: nil, created_at: "2012-08-30 19:28:31", updated_at: "2012-08-30 19:28:31">
```

Any thoughts?  Again, sorry if i have left out any vital info.

Comment: Are you running both the app and the rails console with the same environment?

Comment: why do they differ in the ```updated_at``` column? that looks fishy

Comment: `updated_at`, `created_at`, `active` and of course the `email` field is all different. So it looks like you are using two different databases actually.

Comment: I updated the two results for a more accurate representation of the issue i ma having

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to rebuild your database with rake db:drop db:create db:migrate

This WILL delete all data in your database, but since this is a test app, I assume that's ok.